# BufferdImage heap space error

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory, bufferedimage

I am developing a Java desktop-based application.  Here my work is to put an image into a `JLabel`.  If I load more than 60 images into labels then java shows "Heap space error" (see below.)

I don't want to increase heap space size of JDK.  I just want to free memory after showing the image in the `JLabel`.  I used `flush()` for `BufferedImage`: it does not clear the memory.

Here is my code

```
public static void setImageInLabelFromBufferedImage(JLabel label, int commonWidth, int maxImageHeight, BufferedImage img) {
    try {

        if (img.getWidth() < commonWidth && img.getHeight() < maxImageHeight) {
            **img = Scalr.resize(img, Scalr.Mode.AUTOMATIC, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);**
        } else {
            if (img.getWidth() > img.getHeight()) {
                if (img.getWidth() > commonWidth) {
                    img = Scalr.resize(img, Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH, commonWidth, maxImageHeight, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
                }
            } else if (img.getHeight() > img.getWidth()) {
                if (img.getHeight() > maxImageHeight) {
                    img = Scalr.resize(img, Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_HEIGHT, commonWidth, maxImageHeight, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
                }
            } else {
                img = Scalr.resize(img, Scalr.Mode.FIT_EXACT, commonWidth, maxImageHeight, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
            }
        }

        //BufferedImage resizedImage = Scalr.resize(img, Scalr.Mode.AUTOMATIC, commonWidth, maxImageHeight, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        label.revalidate();
        img.flush();
        img = null;
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("setImageInLabelFromBufferedImage==>" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at 
java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.<init>(DataBufferByte.java:92) at 
java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer(ComponentSampleModel.java:4‌​15) at 
java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Raster.java:944) at 
javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:107‌​3) at 
javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(ImageReader.java:2896) at 
com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:9‌​98) at 
com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:966)
```

Comment: maybe add the full error message in addition to the code

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.<init>(DataBufferByte.java:92)
 at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer(ComponentSampleModel.java:415)
 at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Raster.java:944)
 at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:1073)
 at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(ImageReader.java:2896)
 at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:998)
 at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:966)

Comment: Your `JLabel` with `ImageIcon` will hold onto the `img` reference even if you do null the reference locally. It will need the image data again for every repaint. `flush()`ing a `BufferedImage` doesn't release heap memory, so it's no good. Also the JVM should do a GC, before giving up and throwing OOME, so no need to ask for explicit GC. Seems to me you need to either get rid of some `JLabel`s with `Icon`s, or just increase the JVM heap size.

Comment: but i need jlabel with icon.. is there any other way to do this? i used JtextPane with html content. in this case problem is same.

Answer (score 0):

The decoded image data (much bigger than the compressed image data in JPG/PNG format) has to be held somewhere when displayed and that somewhere is the Heap.

If you mean you want to free up memory for images that are no longer displayed (e.g. someone has scrolled past them) you would have to make sure they cannot be rendered by a paint call (e.g. they are off screen) and then you'd need to not only dispose the image itself, but make sure the JLabel loses it's reference to the image so the GC can collect it -- dispose is just a hint to cleanup the native memory resources used by the image, ultimately you'd need the BufferedImage resource itself GC'ed which means any object referencing it would need to drop it's reference.

This means you probably need a custom component that is clever enough to null & dispose the image reference when scroll off screen and then load it again when it becomes visible again.

Out of the box Swing isn't going to do this for you - you'll need to get creative here (what I mean is without ANY work it won't do this automatically... you can probably use a componentListener and do creative things during visibility events)

Comment: thanks Riyad, if i use a Jpanel , it also cause OOME error , but after it helps for 150 + imges..